# Trigger Worksheet_Change when a user checks a checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to display a time when a user checks a checkbox.

The time should freeze so it doesn't change anytime you open the Excel workbook.
Also, I want to avoid circular references.

With the help of ChatGPT I created the following code.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngC As Range, rngF As Range, rngI As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Define the ranges you want to check
    Set rngC = Me.Range("C2:C10")
    Set rngF = Me.Range("F2:F10")
    Set rngI = Me.Range("I2:I10")

    ' Check if the change occurred within the specified ranges
    For Each cell In rngC
        If Not Intersect(Target, cell) Is Nothing And (cell.Value = True Or cell.Value = 1) Then
            Me.Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value = Now
            Me.Cells(cell.Row, "D").NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
        End If
    Next cell
    
    For Each cell In rngF
        If Not Intersect(Target, cell) Is Nothing And (cell.Value = True Or cell.Value = 1) Then
            Me.Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = Now
            Me.Cells(cell.Row, "G").NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
        End If
    Next cell
    
    For Each cell In rngI
        If Not Intersect(Target, cell) Is Nothing And (cell.Value = True Or cell.Value = 1) Then
            Me.Cells(cell.Row, "J").Value = Now
            Me.Cells(cell.Row, "J").NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

With this code, if I write "True" in one of the cells in question, in the adjacent cell the time is displayed as intended.

If I check a checkbox, in the cell appears a True but the time is not displayed.
Same happens if I create an "If" formula to generate the "True" in the cell.

If I go to the cell that has the "True" generated because the checkbox or the "if" statement of my test, and I go to the formula bar and press "Enter", then the code works and the time is displayed.

I tried, helped again by ChatGPT, modifying the code with `calculate()`.

Comment: The `Change` event doesn't fire after a formula calculates, nor when a checkbox (and linked cell) is updated.

Comment: You can however change the time in the change event of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

insted of

```
Me.Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value = Now
```

use

```
Me.Range("D" & cell.Row).Select
SendKeys "^+;"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
```